# メールサーバの設定が正しく行えているか教えてください。

Tags: dns

お名前ドットコムでドメインを取得し、共有サーバーSDというメールサーバ専用のサーバをレンタルしています。DNSはメールサーバのほうで登録してあり、レコードなどの各種設定は共有サーバーSDで行っています。

案内に従い、support@example.comというメールアカウントを作成してMacのほうで設定を行って送受信のテストを行いました。
送信はすぐに宛先に届きますが、受信が4、5分かかったり、受信できなかったりします。

<その他の情報>
受信メールサーバ:pop8.gmoserver.jp
送信メールサーバ:smtp8.gmoserver.jp

取得したドメインexample.comはAWSのEC2サーバでホームページのドメインとしても利用しており、そこの静的IPアドレスをAレコードで登録しています。

<行ったこと>
当初案内の設定だけでは受信サーバに接続ができなかったため、共有サーバSDで以下2点のMXレコードをついかしました。

```
ホスト:空欄
TYPE:MX
VALUE:pop8.gmoserver.jp
優先度:10

ホスト:空欄
TYPE:MX
VALUE:smtp8.gmoserver.jp
優先度:20
```

<お伺いしたいこと>
メールは届かなかったり、異様に遅かったりで正しく設定できているかわかりませんので、教えてください。

正直プログラミングについての質問ではないと思っており、スタックオーバーフローで伺ってよいのかわかりません。
ですが、他に詳しそうな方がいらっしゃるコミュニティサイトが見つからず、かなり困っているので質問しました。
こういった質問はダメであるということでしたら即刻削除いたしますので、ご指摘下さい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MXレコードは受信メールサーバーを指定するものですので、pop8.gmoserver.jp のみ設定ください。

また、DNS設定ツールの詳細がわかりませんが、ホスト欄が空欄＝ドメイン名(example.com)ということで合っていますか？
Mac で dig コマンドが使えるのであれば、`dig example.com mx` でドメイン example.com に対する MXレコードを確認できると思います。
Mac が参照する DNSサーバーでキャッシュを持っている場合、MXレコードを変更してもすぐには反映されない場合があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！まだ何通かしかテストしてませんが、正しく受信していました。
DNSについては、Taichさんのおっしゃる通りです。digコマンドで反映されていることも確認できました。